# Selenium: Not able to take complete page screenshot using aShot library

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver, ashot

Am trying to take the complete page screenshot both horizontally and vertically using `Firefox gecko` driver and [aShot Library](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/ashot).

However, the results are not as expected. Take a look:

[image]

```
driver.get("https://google.com");

Screenshot fpScreenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(1000)).takeScreenshot(driver);
ImageIO.write(fpScreenshot.getImage(),"JPEG",new File("FullPageScreenshot.jpg"));
```

Looked into a lot of variants but nothing is working. Interestingly, when I try using old firefox version (46), I am able to take full screenshot without any third party library. Am trying to use latest firefox and have full screenshot functionality.

Any help?

Comment: Instead of using aShot Library, why don't you switch to full screen in your browser and then press Windows + Print Screen keys using Selenium?

Comment: And how to convert that to a jpeg file?

Comment: Check if these links help you: https://www.mkyong.com/java/convert-png-to-jpeg-image-file-in-java/
 and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290336/converting-png-into-jpeg

Answer (score 16):

Try:

```
Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(ShootingStrategies.scaling(1.75f), 1000)).takeScreenshot(driver);
```

where 1.75f is device pixel ratio (you can run `window.devicePixelRatio;` in browser console to find it).
If it's still not capturing full screen, change it to 2f

Comment: I needed to add a scaling strategy to the viewport pasting to get it to work, otherwise, it was getting cut off. Thank you for adding complementary useful info to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

While working with *Selenium Java Client v3.12.0*, *ChromeDriver v2.40*, *Chrome v 67.0* using **ashot-1.4.4.jar** here is an example to take the *complete page screenshot* both horizontally and vertically using **ChromeDriver** and **aShot Library** of the *url* `https://jquery.com/`:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import java.io.File;
  import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.AShot;
  import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.Screenshot;
  import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.shooting.ShootingStrategies;

  public class ashot_CompletePage {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

          System.setProperty("god.bless.you", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
          options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
          WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.get("https://jquery.com/");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("jQuery"));
          Screenshot myScreenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(100)).takeScreenshot(driver);
          ImageIO.write(myScreenshot.getImage(),"PNG",new File("./Screenshots/elementScreenshot.png"));
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```
- Screenshots:

[image: screenshot]

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion in [How to take screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/how-to-take-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver/55120087#55120087)

Comment: Tried some travel sites like booking.com/expedia.com and result is: vertically complete screenshot but horizontally half.

Comment: `ShootingStrategies` is not available in 1.4.4 version but is available in 1.5.2 version of aShot. Am trying that only.

Comment: @DebanjanB How can I screen a full vertical size with exactly horizontal size? i.e. 1920xFullSize, 1280xFullSize etc...

Comment: @EugeneTruuts The default strategy should work. Else can you raise a new question with your exact requirements so I can construct an answer for your question?

Comment: @DebanjanB https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52705346/how-can-i-screen-a-full-vertical-size-with-exactly-horizontal-size