# How can I screen a full vertical size with exactly horizontal size?

Tags: java, google-chrome, automation, webdriver, ashot

I use a Selenium with the Ashot framework to make screenshots of the entire page

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);


Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(100)).takeScreenshot(driver);
```

This shooting strategy works fine, I can get the full-sized screenshot.
I received the screenshot with 1200 width x Full Size of my webpage, but I need to screenshot my webpage with different width sizes, for example, 1920xFullSize, 1280xFullSize etc.
I tried  to use Dimension to set exactly width:

```
Dimension d = new Dimension(1920,720 );
driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
```

but if I use a Dimension, the entire vertical size screenshot doesn't work and I receive 1920x720 image.

How can I screenshot 1920xFullSize, 1280xFullSize etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Selenium Grid in Docker container where I set the dimensions I need.