# How can I convert png/gif/jpg in grails to jpg maintaining a high quality in the image?

Tags: java, grails, image-processing, jpeg, image-resizing

I use the following method for converting images to jpg. The problem with my solution is that it will reduce the quality to much.

What is a good way to maintain quality of the image, while reducing the file size?

```
def convertToJpg(currentImage) {
    try {
         InputStream inStreamCrop = new ByteArrayInputStream(currentImage)
         BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(inStreamCrop)

         // create a blank, RGB, same width and height, and a white background
         BufferedImage newBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(bufferedImage.getWidth(),
               bufferedImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
         newBufferedImage.createGraphics().drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, Color.WHITE, null);

         ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream()
         // write to jpeg file
         ImageIO.write(newBufferedImage, "jpg", baos);
         baos.flush()
         def image = baos.toByteArray()
         baos.close()
         return image

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: check out http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/

Comment: The compression obtained with JPEG will vary greatly based on the image contents. Once you've reduced the colors to produce a GIF or 8-bit PNG the compression you get from JPEG won't be as good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the quality of the JPEG by getting an [`ImageWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html) object and setting it through the parameters.  For example:

```
import javax.imageio.stream.*
import javax.imageio.*

BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("test.png"));
float quality = 0.9;
ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next();
ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionQuality(quality);
writer.setOutput(new FileImageOutputStream(new File("test.jpg")));
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(bufferedImage, null, null), param);
```

The quality parameter can range between 0 and 1, with 1 having the least compression.  Try different values; I've found 0.9 is a good choice for low compression (but large file sizes).

Note that JPEG images are not supported with OpenJDK: [ImageIO not able to write a JPEG file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432388/imageio-not-able-to-write-a-jpeg-file)

Comment: can you provide the full code example using my code and your modification?

Comment: I've updated my code to a fully working example.  Also, note that JPG images can be problematic with OpenJDK; make sure you're using a Sun/Oracle JVM.

Comment: The output stream must be an implementation of `ImageOutputStream`.

Comment: could you please be more specific? How do I have to write it?

Comment: Wrap your `ByteArrayOutputStream` with a `MemoryCacheImageOutputStream`.

Comment: I did not get it, can you edit you code in order to make it work? Thanks for your help.