# Why IIOImageException java showing

Tags: java

what the cause of `javax.imageio.IIOException: Sample size must be <= 8`.
i try to write IIOImage like this

```
public static byte[] compressImage(BufferedImage imageSource, float quality) throws IOException {
    Iterator i = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg");

    ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) i.next();
    ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    iwp.setCompressionQuality(quality);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageOutputStream output = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(bos);
    writer.setOutput(output);
    IIOImage image = new IIOImage(imageSource, null, null); 
    writer.write(null, image, iwp);
    writer.dispose();

    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

but when ImageWriter try to write IIOImage, the exception was showing. I don't know what's wrong, but if the image size big, there's no exception showing and run perfectly, but if image size is small then `javax.imageio.IIOException: Sample size must be <= 8` is showing. Iam sorry for my bad English, thanks for any reply to my question. Oh and here's the complete trace

```
Caused by: javax.imageio.IIOException: Sample size must be <= 8
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.writeOnThread(JPEGImageWriter.java:494) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.write(JPEGImageWriter.java:360) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
at com.daksa.cms.util.ImageCompressor.compressImage(ImageCompressor.java:37) ~[CmsServer-ejb_jar/:na]
at com.daksa.cms.util.ImageCompressor.compressImageToSize(ImageCompressor.java:47) ~[CmsServer-ejb_jar/:na]
at com.daksa.cms.bean.PersoEventBean.resizeImage(PersoEventBean.java:292) ~[CmsServer-ejb_jar/:na]
... 85 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you should use

```
com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg.CLibJPEGImageWriter
```

class for rendering the image. See **[THIS](http://www.dcm4che.org/jira/browse/DCMEE-368)** link. You can also have a look at the following:

1. http://www.codingtiger.com/questions/java/ImageIO-not-able-to-write-a-JPEG-file.html
2. [ImageIO not able to write a JPEG file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432388/imageio-not-able-to-write-a-jpeg-file)

Comment: Where i can download that lib?

Comment: From [HERE](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.media/jai_imageio/1.1/). Are you using OpenJDk?

Answer (score 0):

know i know the problem, iam sorry the image format is wrong, it should be .jpg