# how to convert a gif image to jpg?

Tags: java

like this 
[gif image](http://ec.europa.eu/culture/media/programme/images/logos/01_tr_media_col/01_tr_media_col_gif.gif)

it has transparent background,

when i using `ImageIO.write(image,"jpg", file)` to save,it's be broken

the broken result is [here](http://clip2net.com/clip/m10494/1284584778-clip-29kb.jpg)

how to fix it problem? thank you

my code:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class ImageResize1  extends TestCase{

    public void testT1() throws IOException{
        URL url=new URL("http://ec.europa.eu/culture/media/programme/images/logos/01_tr_media_col/01_tr_media_col_gif.gif");
        BufferedImage image=ImageIO.read(url);
        File file=new File("C:/temp/java/t7.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(image,"jpg", file);
    }
}
```

i used:

```
for(int x = 0; x < scaled.getWidth(); x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < scaled.getHeight(); y++) {
        int rgb = scaled.getRGB(x, y);
        int alpha = (rgb >> 24) & 0xff;
        if(alpha != 255) {
            scaled.setRGB(x, y,-1); //set white
        }
    }
}
```

check it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464825/converting-transparent-gif-png-to-jpeg-using-java)

it's not right,result is [here](http://clip2net.com/clip/m10494/1284584873-clip-24kb.jpg)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464825/converting-transparent-gif-png-to-jpeg-using-java

Comment: JPEG is a lossy format designed for photographs, and is bad for an image with sharp edges, like a diagram or the provided logo. It will look fuzzy and ugly. I recommend PNG instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AreaAveragingScaleFilter scaleFilter =
    new AreaAveragingScaleFilter(
                Math.round(originalWidth / factorX),
                Math.round(originalHeight / factorY));
ImageProducer producer = new FilteredImageSource(original.getSource(), scaleFilter);
ImageGenerator generator = new ImageGenerator();
producer.startProduction(generator);
BufferedImage scaled = generator.getImage();

for(int x = 0; x < scaled.getWidth(); x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < scaled.getHeight(); y++) {
        int rgb = scaled.getRGB(x, y);
        int alpha = (rgb >> 24) & 0xff;
        if(alpha != 255) {
            scaled.setRGB(x, y,-1); //set white
        }
    }
}


JPEGImageWriteParam param = new JPEGImageWriteParam(null);
param.setCompressionMode(JPEGImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionQuality((float) 0.85);
java.util.Iterator<ImageWriter> it = ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("jpg");
ImageWriter writer = it.next();
dest.getParentFile().mkdirs();
writer.setOutput(new FileImageOutputStream(dest));
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(scaled, null, null), param);
writer.dispose();
```

Check it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464825/converting-transparent-gif-png-to-jpeg-using-java)

Answer (score 2):

JPG doesn't support transparency, so you can't.

Try using PNG, TIFF or GIF instead.

Comment: i don't need transparency, i want a white(#FFFFFF) background

Comment: Hum, sorry, that wasn't specified in your question. What do you mean by "it's broken"?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the code as I'm not a Java guru, but...

The JPEG format doesn't support transparent backgrounds, so if you're expecting that to be retained, it won't happen.

(not sure why you're doing the conversion, but if you need a high-colour format that does support transparency, use PNG instead)

Answer (score 0):

Converting from one format to another is just the beginning :) if it was me I'll use ImageMagik by passing the command to OS and let the ImageMagick take care of the rest

[ImageMagick homepage](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

Beside converting you can resize, add text and almost do all the photoshop tricks on your newly created image and it is easy.