# png file turn all black when compress to jpeg. Is it because PNG is lossless?

Tags: java, compression, png, jpeg, javax.imageio

I have a piece of code that compress an jpg image with a certain quality, but when the image is png type, they all turn black. Any idea why and how to fix it? here is my code.

```
public void compressImage(String filename, ServletContext servletContext) {
    //You first need to enumerate the image writers that are available to jpg
    Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
    //Then, choose the first image writer available
    ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) iter.next();
    //instantiate an ImageWriteParam object with default compression options
    ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    //Set the compression quality
    iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    iwp.setCompressionQuality(0.5f);
    try {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
        String destPath = "/Users/KingdomHeart/resources/scholar/compress/compress.jpg";
        File file = new File(destPath);
        FileImageOutputStream output = new FileImageOutputStream(file);
        writer.setOutput(output);
        IIOImage image = new IIOImage(img, null, null);
        writer.write(null, image, iwp);
        writer.dispose();
    }catch(IOException e){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might have the answers you're looking for: [Converting transparent gif / png to jpeg using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464825/converting-transparent-gif-png-to-jpeg-using-java)

The issue is likely that you're working with a PNG that has some transparency in it.