# Convert .png to .gif in java 1.5

Tags: java, png, gif

I have a QR code generated in .png format. I want this file to be converted into .gif format for using it in a device. I was trying to use ImageIO class but gif is not supported in java 1.5 but in java 1.6 . Our production servers has java 1.5 and is there any way to convert a .png file to .gif using Java 1.5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting transparent gif / png to jpeg using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464825/converting-transparent-gif-png-to-jpeg-using-java)

Comment: @NimChimpsky: It's not a duplicate. As written, ImageIO did not support writing GIFs in Java 5 due to patent issues.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather use some command-line conversion tool (eg ImageMagick). But if in your environment that's not possible or practical, and if you want to do it in Java, you can try [this backport](http://www.jakobnielsen.net/java6-gif-backport/).

Bear in mind that the conversion is not trivial if the PNG is true colour or has transparency, GIF is more limited.

Answer (score 0):

Direct conversion from png to gif is not possible. so First try to convert png to jpg format and try to convert jpg to gif format.