# Selenium - TakesScreenshot - java - trouble converting to jpg

Tags: selenium, javax.imageio, takesscreenshot

I have the following java method, which successfully creates the png file:

```
        TakesScreenshot scrShot = ((TakesScreenshot) webdriver);
        File SrcFile = scrShot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        File DestFile = new File(fileWithPath + featureFileName + ".png");
//        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(SrcFile);
//        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File(fileWithPath + featureFileName + ".jpg"));
        FileUtils.copyFile(SrcFile, DestFile);
```

I'm trying to convert the image to jpg using the 2 commented lines, but `jpg` output file is not being produced. No error. No file. I can't figure out why. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: maybe see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464825/converting-transparent-gif-png-to-jpeg-using-java  You might also consider copying the file first... it'll be a temporary file marked to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely using OpenJDK that is having number of issues with JPG encoding, especially when you convert from png.

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8211748
- [ImageIO not able to write a JPEG file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432388/imageio-not-able-to-write-a-jpeg-file)

So that your workaround would be to convert image `BufferedImage` to another `BufferedImage` and then save it like:

```java
try {
    TakesScreenshot scrShot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver);
    File SrcFile = scrShot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    BufferedImage pngImage  = ImageIO.read(SrcFile);
    int height = pngImage.getHeight();
    int width = pngImage.getWidth();
    BufferedImage jpgImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    jpgImage.createGraphics().drawImage(pngImage, new AffineTransform(1f,0f,0f,1f,0,0), null);
    ImageIO.write(jpgImage, "jpg", new File("/your_path/output.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since we are already using ashot for full page screen shots, I ended up going with that for regular screen shots. That worked fine with minimal code changes.